# Failed to execute command: No such file or directory (Gunicorn) (Django)

Tags: django, linux, sockets, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

First I have created a socket named 'receiver.socket'

```
(nvenv) papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ cat cat /etc/systemd/system/receiver.socket
cat: cat: No such file or directory
[Unit]
Description=receiver socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/receiver.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Then, I created a service file with the same name 'receiver.service'

```
(nvenv) papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ cat /etc/systemd/system/receiver.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=receiver.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=papli
Group=papli
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn
WorkingDirectory=/datadrive/receiver/GisServer
Environment="PATH=/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin"
ExecStart=/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /datadrive/sender/log/gunicorn.log  --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/receiver.sock GisServer.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that

```
sudo systemctl enable receiver
sudo systemctl start receiver
```

Error that I am getting

```
(nvenv) papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ sudo systemctl status receiver
● receiver.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/receiver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-03-19 07:14:09 UTC; 3min 38s ago
 Main PID: 6029 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 19 07:14:09 sender systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Mar 19 07:14:09 sender systemd[6029]: receiver.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Mar 19 07:14:09 sender systemd[6029]: receiver.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin/gunicorn: No
Mar 19 07:14:09 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 19 07:14:09 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Troubleshooting Steps I followed

1. Checked sock file is created.

```
(nvenv) papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ ls /run/receiver.sock
/run/receiver.sock
```

2. Inside nvenv/bin gunicorn file is present and their permissions are adequate

```
(nvenv) papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ ls -la nvenv/bin/gunicorn
-rwxrwxrwx 1 papli papli 258 Feb 25 08:25 nvenv/bin/gunicorn
```

3. Checked the binding

```
(nvenv) papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 GisServer.wsgi
[2022-03-19 07:29:22 +0000] [7456] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2022-03-19 07:29:22 +0000] [7456] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (7456)
[2022-03-19 07:29:22 +0000] [7456] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-03-19 07:29:22 +0000] [7459] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7459
static dir:  /datadrive/receiver/GisServer/static
^C[2022-03-19 07:29:24 +0000] [7456] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2022-03-19 07:29:25 +0000] [7456] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Can somebody guide me in which I have made a mistake?

Thanks

**EDIT**
When I run this

```
papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ curl --unix-socket /run/receiver.sock localhost
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Normally it should return an HTML code, right? How could I solve this?

After spending 2 Hrs on debugging I found there was an extra space in the command. Now the error has changed!

```
papli@sender:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status receiver
● receiver.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/receiver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-03-19 10:12:35 UTC; 25s ago
  Process: 3001 ExecStart=/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /datadrive/sender/log/gunicorn.log --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock GisServe
 Main PID: 3001 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: receiver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 10:12:35 sender systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
papli@sender:/etc/systemd/system$
```

Comment: WorkingDirectory=/datadrive/receiver/GisServer
can you go to this directory, and type "pwd", it will show your actuall working directory

Comment: i've made a look a like guide in different thread, but with some different approach, it might help also, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71444214/14632651, in your way `Mar 19 07:14:09 sender systemd[6029]: receiver.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory` i believe error seems here `ExecStart=/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /datadrive/sender/log/gunicorn.log  --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/receiver.sock GisServer.wsgi:application` in paths

Comment: @oruchkin I have checked the paths ````papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ pwd
/datadrive/receiver/GisServer````

Comment: @oruchkin Also I have checked that you mentioned
````papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ ls /datadrive/sender/log/gunicorn.log
/datadrive/sender/log/gunicorn.log````

Comment: ````papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ ls /datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin/gunicorn
/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/nvenv/bin/gunicorn````
````papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer$ ls /run/receiver.sock
/run/receiver.sock
````

All of them exists still the error persists?

Comment: are `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` inside this folder `/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/GisServer` ?

Comment: @oruchkin, Yes. here

````python
papli@sender:/datadrive/receiver/GisServer/GisServer$ ls
__pycache__  settings.py  static  urls.py  wsgi.py
````

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243086/discussion-between-oruchkin-and-pradyum-gupta).